# How to access a variable from a class of another module

Tags: python, class, global

I am a total python beginner and I have a variable created in a class of a file commandline_reader.py that I want to access from another script. I tried to do it by making the variable global, which doesn't work.

myscript.py:

```
    from commandline_reader import Commandline_Reader
    reader = Commandline_Reader('--get_serial_number')
    reader.run()

    print output
```

commandline_reader.py:

```
    class Commandline_Reader:
        def __init__(self,argString=''):
            global output
            output = []

        def run(self):
            # do stuff
            a = 'somevariable'
            output.append(a)
```

When I run myscript.py I always get a NameError: name 'output' is not defined. I've read that this is because global variables are only defined within a module. How do I correctly access the output variable in my script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just return the Value from the run() Method

myscript.py:

```
from commandline_reader import Commandline_Reader
reader = Commandline_Reader('--get_serial_number')
output = reader.run()

print output
```

commandline_reader.py:

```
class Commandline_Reader:
    def __init__(self,argString=''):
        self.output = []

    def run(self):
        # do stuff
        a = 'somevariable'
        self.output.append(a)
        return self.output
```

Comment: You mean *self*.output, the way it's now, output = [] in init does nothing. Also list.append returns None, so you shouldn't return it.

Comment: the scope of output in your code does not know about the init function without an instance attribute self. This will still return a name error.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was such a trivial solution!!

Comment: @Mailerdaimon you are returning variable, but the thing how to access variables globally   accross the modules.

Answer (score 1):

Make `output` an instance attribute:

```
class Commandline_Reader:
    def __init__(self,argString=''):
        self.output = [] # note use of self here
    def run(self):
        # do stuff
        a = 'somevariable'
        self.output.append(a) # and here
```

The access it via the instance:

```
print reader.output
```

Answer (score 1):

ouch. The whole reason object oriented programming takes place is to avoid the use of global variables. Make them instance variables to access them anywhere in the class.

```
class Commandline_Reader:
    def __init__(self,argString=''):
        self.output = []

    def run(self):
        # do stuff
        a = 'somevariable'
        self.output.append(a) #output is now part of the instance Commandline reader and can be accessed anywhere inside the class. 


 clr = Commandline_Reader(argstring='--get_serial_number')
 clr.run()
 print clr.output
 >>>['somevariable']
```

Comment: Well there are lots of reasons. But I can't think of a reason why you would ever need global variables in a class.

Comment: For instance, you want to share a data between few @staticmethods, you would need a global variable in that class isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [class attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) is more appropriate for you?

```
class Commandline_Reader:

    output = []

    def run(self):
        # do stuff
        a = 'somevariable'
        self.output.append(a)
```